# Replace character only when character not in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like the following:

```
test_string = "test:(apple:orange,(orange:apple)):test2"
```

I want to replace ":" with "/" only if it is not contained within any set of parentheses.

The desired output is  "test/(apple:orange,(orange:apple))/test2"

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: @user5173426 Please see edited post. Thanks!

Comment: Go through the characters, increase a counter on `(`, decrease on `)`, replace if character matches and counter is `0`. Happy implementing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module:

```
>>> import regex
>>> test_string = "test:(apple:orange,(orange:apple)):test2"
>>> regex.sub(r'\((?:[^()]++|(?0))++\)(*SKIP)(*F)|:', '/', test_string)
'test/(apple:orange,(orange:apple))/test2'
```

- `\((?:[^()]++|(?0))++\)` match pair of parantheses recursively

  - See [Recursive Regular Expressions](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) for explanations
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` to avoid replacing the preceding pattern

  - See [Backtracking Control Verbs](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) for explanations
- `|:` to specify `:` as alternate match

Comment: it's cool!!!!
If you don't mind can you share resource from where you learn these kind of regex?

Comment: @Mayur from lots of places, some of it have from `regex` tag here on SO, some from the links mentioned in the answer. I have put together a [list of resources](https://github.com/learnbyexample/py_regular_expressions/blob/master/Resources_list.md) on github, might help

Comment: Thanks! What if instead of parentheses, I wanted to check if it is inside brackets `{…}`?

Comment: @JackArnestad change all the parentheses to braces, except the pairs that start with `(?`

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code to achive expected ouput

```
def solve(args):
    ans=''
    seen = 0
    for i in args:
        if i == '(':
            seen += 1
        elif i== ')':
            seen -= 1
        if i == ':' and seen <= 0:
            ans += '/'
        else:
            ans += i
    return ans

test_string = "test:(apple:orange,(orange:apple)):test2"
print(solve(test_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the first opening parentheses
2. Find the last closing parentheses
3. Replace every ":" with "/" before the first opening parentheses
4. Don't do anything to the middle part
5. Replace every ":" with "/" after the last closing parentheses
6. Put these 3 substrings together

Code:

```
test_string = "test:(apple:orange,(orange:apple)):test2"
first_opening = test_string.find('(')
last_closing = test_string.rfind(')')
result_string = test_string[:first_opening].replace(':', '/') + test_string[first_opening : last_closing] +  test_string[last_closing:].replace(':', '/')
print(result_string)
```

Output:

```
test/(apple:orange,(orange:apple))/test2
```

Warning: as the comments pointed it out this won't work if there are multiple distinct parentheses :(

Comment: This won't scale for nested parentheses of an arbitrary depth.

Comment: Works on this specific example; does not work on general case that fits OP's description (e.g.: `(apple:orange):test:(orange:apple)`)